# Trying to make different HTML paragraph show depending on selection

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this modal that is supposed to provide a different descriptive paragraph depending on which which selection the user has made from a dropdown. Currently it just shows all paragraphs at all times. I want it to show 'Hide' when Public is selected, 'Hide2' when 'Internal' is selected. Etc. Etc.

```html
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">

 function CheckSelect(val){
 var PUBLIC=document.getElementById('Hide');
 var INTERNAL=document.getElementById('Hide2');
 var CONFIDENTIAL=document.getElementById('Hide3');
 var SECRET=document.getElementById('Hide4');

 if(val=='PUBLIC')
   PUBLIC.style.display='block';
 else if (val=='INTERNAL')
   INTERNAL.style.display='block';
    else if (val=='CONFIDENTIAL')
   CONFIDENTIAL.style.display='block';
    else if (val=='SECRET')
   SECRET.style.display='block';
   else 
   PUBLIC.style.display='none';

}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<select id="selectDocumentType" name="documentClass" onchange='CheckSelect(this.value);'>
  <option value="Choose">Choose a classification!</option>
  <option value="PUBLIC">Public</option>
  <option value="INTERNAL">Internal</option>
  <option value="CONFIDENTIAL">Confidential</option>
  <option value="SECRET">Secret</option>
  </select>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;" class="light"
         id="Hide" style='display:none;'>Wizard Is working</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;" class="light"
         id="Hide2" style='display:none;'>Wizard Is Twerking</p>         
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;" class="light"
         id="Hide3" style='display:none;'>Wizard Is Laughing</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;" class="light"
         id="Hide4" style='display:none;'>Wizard Is Eating</p>  
</body>
```

Comment: You should start by moving the display:none style from its own style attribute into the main style attribute for each paragraph element. You should then initialize each of the paragraphs to "hidden" at the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code's missing the logic of 'if appropriate value is selected, don't hide, else hide'; i.e. your `if` statement is incorrect.

That being said, it's better replaced with `classList.toggle('show', <predicate>` in order to avoid repeating (4 times) essentially the same if/else statement.

There are a bunch of other issues with your code regarding readability and best practices. I won't enumerate all of them, but below is what you should be aiming for.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('#selectDocumentType').addEventListener('change', () => {
 [
  ['public', 'hide'],
  ['internal', 'hide2'],
  ['confidential', 'hide3'],
  ['secret', 'hide4'],
 ].forEach(([value, elId]) => $(`#${elId}`).classList.toggle('show', value === $('#selectDocumentType').value));
});
```

```css
p.light {
  font-family: helvetica, garamond, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  display: none;
}

p.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select id="selectDocumentType" name="documentClass">
 <option value="Choose">Choose a classification!</option>
 <option value="public">Public</option>
 <option value="internal">Internal</option>
 <option value="confidential">Confidential</option>
 <option value="secret">Secret</option>
</select>
<p class="light hidden" id="hide">Wizard Is working</p>
<p class="light hidden" id="hide2">Wizard Is Twerking</p>
<p class="light hidden" id="hide3">Wizard Is Laughing</p>
<p class="light hidden" id="hide4">Wizard Is Eating</p>
```

Edit, clean code practices:

1) Use `document.querySelector` instead of `document.getElementById` because it's more versatile. It's often bound to `$` for less typing.

2) Use `let` & `const` instead of `var` to declare variables. Use upper case variable names only for `const`s and lower case for non `const`s.

3) Use `switch` statements instead of repeated `if/else` comparing the same variable for equality.

4) Use `===` instead of `==`.

5) Properly format your code. E.g., indentation and spaces surrounding operators.

6) Prefer arrow functions `() => {}` instead of the `function` keyword.

7) Use `element.addEventListener('event')` in JS instead of `onevent` in HTML.

8) Don't capitalize HTML values (e.g. ID's, classes, etc). Use dash case, e.g. `id="min-value-input"`.

9) There is no `align` attribute for `<p>` tags.

10) Don't use the `style` attribute in HTML. Likewise, don't set `style` properties in JS. Instead, use the `class` attribute in HTML, and `element.classList.add|remove|toggle` in JS.

11) `regular` is not a valid CSS `font-style` value. You proably meant `normal`.

Comment: Oh man. If you wanted to enumerate the best practices problems I would be very appreciative. I'm only just starting to learn this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing too much of your original code, just set the other items to display `none` when you set the certain one to `display` in your `if-else` statements. Also delete the extra `style` attributes in your html code where you have `display:none` and add that to the first `style` attribute within the `p` tag. Hopefully this helps

```html
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">

 function CheckSelect(val){
 var PUBLIC=document.getElementById('Hide');
 var INTERNAL=document.getElementById('Hide2');
 var CONFIDENTIAL=document.getElementById('Hide3');
 var SECRET=document.getElementById('Hide4');

 if(val=='PUBLIC'){
   PUBLIC.style.display='block';
   INTERNAL.style.display='none';
   CONFIDENTIAL.style.display='none';
   SECRET.style.display='none';
   }
 else if (val=='INTERNAL'){
   INTERNAL.style.display='block';
   PUBLIC.style.display='none';
   CONFIDENTIAL.style.display='none';
   SECRET.style.display='none';
   }
 else if (val=='CONFIDENTIAL'){
   CONFIDENTIAL.style.display='block';
   PUBLIC.style.display='none';
   INTERNAL.style.display='none';
   SECRET.style.display='none';
   }
 else if (val=='SECRET'){
   SECRET.style.display='block';
   PUBLIC.style.display='none';
   INTERNAL.style.display='none';
   CONFIDENTIAL.style.display='none';
   }
 else {
   PUBLIC.style.display='none';
   SECRET.style.display='none';
   INTERNAL.style.display='none';
   CONFIDENTIAL.style.display='none';
   }
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<select id="selectDocumentType" name="documentClass" onchange='CheckSelect(this.value);'>
  <option value="Choose">Choose a classification!</option>
  <option value="PUBLIC">Public</option>
  <option value="INTERNAL">Internal</option>
  <option value="CONFIDENTIAL">Confidential</option>
  <option value="SECRET">Secret</option>
  </select>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light"
         id="Hide" >Wizard Is working</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light"
         id="Hide2">Wizard Is Twerking</p>         
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light"
         id="Hide3">Wizard Is Laughing</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light"
         id="Hide4">Wizard Is Eating</p>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Things i modified in your code:

- Added a new **class tag** in your `<p> tag "work"`
- Added a **common function** to hide all items of class *work*
- I updated the id of your `<p> tag as the value in option`
- 3rd step helped me simply pass the value to set the visibility of required `<p> tag`

```html
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">

function HideAll(val)
{
 var all = document.getElementsByClassName(val);
  for(var i =0; i<all.length; i++)
   all[i].style.display = 'none';
}
 function CheckSelect(val){
 
  HideAll('work');
 document.getElementById(val).style.display='block';
 

}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<select id="selectDocumentType" name="documentClass" onchange='CheckSelect(this.value);'>
  <option value="Choose">Choose a classification!</option>
  <option value="PUBLIC">Public</option>
  <option value="INTERNAL">Internal</option>
  <option value="CONFIDENTIAL">Confidential</option>
  <option value="SECRET">Secret</option>
  </select>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:block;" class="light work"
         id="Choose" >Please Choose any one</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light work"
         id="PUBLIC" >Wizard Is working</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light work"
         id="INTERNAL" >Wizard Is Twerking</p>         
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light work"
         id="CONFIDENTIAL" >Wizard Is Laughing</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light work"
         id="SECRET" >Wizard Is Eating</p>  
</body>
</html>
```

`You should keep the styles commonly in styles since it's repeated`