# Reinvestigating "Trying to make different HTML paragraph show depending on selection"

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I asked about this [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991014/trying-to-make-different-html-paragraph-show-depending-on-selection) but failed to provide enough detail so I thought I'd give credit where it's due (the responses were excellent, but didn't answer my issue because I'd failed to provide enough information) and start over.

So I have this pair of modals; one that accepts a text input, and one that gets input out of a dropdown selection, in [google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HjIyY6MUKmQghQOWTD4T2dNjAZ9jrOX-OXFkYUyWnAs/edit?usp=sharing) and [scripts](https://script.google.com/d/19Wqa8peG5JoC2vvDRK51mkqndPRcaByoUpH2ul6y_LQBPv2eKReH0dYR/edit?usp=sharing) (see hyperlinks) that is supposed to provide a different descriptive paragraph depending on which which selection the user has made from a dropdown step. Currently it just shows a single paragraph that doesn't change depending on selection. I want it to:

- show id='PUBLIC' paragraph when Public is selected, show id='INTERNAL' when internal is selected. Etc. Etc.
- Save their selection and send it to be pasted it where it's needed.

```js
function AddValuesFromModal(selectValue) {
  var documentId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  console.log("Getting document log...");
 var infoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Information Control')
  console.log("Got document!");
  console.log("Selected value: " + selectValue);
  console.log("Start setting value....");
  infoSheet.getRange('C4').setValue(selectValue);
  console.log("Value has been set!");
}

function myFunk() {
  // Display a dialog box for each field you need information for.
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  //var response = ui.prompt('Enter Name', 'Enter owners person's name', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var nameResponse = ui.prompt("Enter the name of the document OWNER");
  var salesperson = nameResponse.getResponseText();
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var infoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Information Control')
  var date = new Date();
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_myHtml")
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(200)
    .setHeight(150);

  var modal = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  modal.showModalDialog(htmlDlg, "Document Classification");

  //Get Current Document ID
  var documentId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  console.log(documentId);

  //Get the document body as a variable
  var body = SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentId).getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(body);

  //Insert the entries into the document
  infoSheet.getRange('C5').setValue(salesperson);
  infoSheet.getRange('C8').setValue(date);



}
```

```html
<form id="docType">
<select id="selectDocumentType" name="documentClass" onchange='CheckSelect(this.value);'>
  <option value="PUBLIC">Public</option>
  <option value="INTERNAL">Internal</option>
  <option value="CONFIDENTIAL">Confidential</option>
  <option value="SECRET">Secret</option>
</select>       
<body>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:block;" class="light work"
         id="Choose" >Please Choose any one</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light work"
         id="PUBLIC" >Wizard Is working</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light work"
         id="INTERNAL" >Wizard Is Twerking</p>         
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light work"
         id="CONFIDENTIAL" >Wizard Is Laughing</p>
<p align="justify" style="font-family:helvetica,garamond,serif;font-size:12px;font-style:regular;display:none;" class="light work"
         id="SECRET" >Wizard Is Eating</p>  
</body>
<hr/>
 <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit();" value="Submit" />
</form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>

    function HideAll(val)
{
 var all = document.getElementsByClassName(val);
  for(var i =0; i<all.length; i++)
   all[i].style.display = 'none';
}
 function CheckSelect(val){
 
  HideAll('work');
 document.getElementById(val).style.display='block';
 

}
    function formSubmit(){
    Submit();
    }
   
    
    function Submit() {
    var selectedValue = $('#selectDocumentType').val();
    console.log(selectedValue);
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(closeIt)
        .AddValuesFromModal(selectedValue);
      };
      
    function closeIt(){
      google.script.host.close();
    };
    

    </script>
```

Comment: Cannot call getRange of null is a pretty common problem.  It just means that either the spreadsheet or the sheet is not defined.  So go find out why.

Comment: I don't see any Javascript function named  'CheckColors'

Comment: I really tried to lay this one out clearly and think it through. Sorry for ticking you off with such a medial issue.

Comment: I'm not upset at all. Just trying to help.

Comment: Well you sure did help. Thank you so much. I forgot to name the spreadsheet, and it was the 'CheckColors' issue.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the script. "CheckColors" should have been "CheckSelect". Bad version control *facepalm*.

Comment: I was thinking that must be the case.  Now you can check your own answer off.